# play framework custom module in different directory

Tags: java, model-view-controller, module, playframework, playframework-1.x

i am trying to learn more about custom modules in play framework. i created a play application (v1.2.5) using the command line.

> play new myApp

then i created three modules in the same directory

> play new-module myModule1
>
> play new-module myModule2
>
> play new-module myModule3

the directory is in the following condition

> /myApplicationDirectory
>
> > > /myApp
> > >
> > > /myModule1
> > >
> > > /myModule2
> > >
> > > /myModule3

the following is my "dependencies.yml" file

```
    require:
        - play
        - customModules -> myModule1
        - customModules -> myModule2
        - customModules -> myModule3

    # Custom repository
    repositories:
        - customModules:
            type:       local
            artifact:   "/path/to/app/modules/"
            contains:
                - myModule1
                - myModule2
                - myModule3
```

in my modules directory under myApp, there are three files named "myModule1","myModule2" and "myModule3". In these files, absolute paths to these modules are written only.

Now, when I run the "myApp" from command line, it says that these three modules are available. I can add java files etc. to these modules manually from Finder. However, I want to open these modules in IntelliJ. But modules are not IntelliJ projects. They are also not being idealized or eclipsified from command line. I want to put them into IntelliJ too. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem exactly, when you say the modules are not being idealized / eclipsified from command line? Doesn't the `play idealize` command work for them? If not, try to add an (empty) `application.conf` file into the module's `conf` folder. Then put the following line in that file:

```
application.name=[your_module_name]
```

I seem to recall a bug with eclipsify / idealize commands and modules, and that may have been the workaround.